# 'Get latest version' not working as expected

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I am confused about these two very similar source control settings in Visual Studio.

- *Get latest version of item on check-out in a server workspace*
- *Enable get latest on check-out*

The first is your personal options, presumably global for all solutions.
The other is specific for the source control project and is shared between users just for that project.

But they don't behave as expected.  The only way I can find to prevent getting the latest version on check-out is to uncheck *both* settings.

Is this correct? 
I need to find a way to only do this for one project and for all users of that project. I am using server workspaces.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's correct. If you want to disable get latest version on checkout.

Please make sure that both “Enable Get Latest on Check Out” box on **Team Project level** and on  "Get latest version of item on check-out in a server workspace" on **Tools menu**  is cleared.

**If you enable either one, you may be forced to get latest version upon checking out.**

In addition, please make sure the files you want to check out in the Source Control belongs to the team project you have disabled the “Enable Get Latest on Check Out” box. As just as I mentioned above, the “Enable Get Latest on Check Out” box is on the team project level instead of the team project collection level.

So if you are checking out files which belong to one team project with “Enable Get Latest on Check Out” box selected.

Even though you have disabled local setting in Tools, the latest files of that specific team project should also be checked out automatically.

Take a look at this similar question here: [Checkout automatically Gets Latest version eventhough 'Get latest version of item on check out' option is not selected](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/269bf73d-f83e-4f07-9005-3024953e3f96/checkout-automatically-gets-latest-version-eventhough-get-latest-version-of-item-on-check-out?forum=tfsversioncontrol)

**Note:** To see the change, it may works only after your restart Visual Studio when you changed settings (check/uncheck).

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but doesn't that seem a bit strange for it to work like this.  Why have both settings available if they don't work together.   The wording 'Enable Get Latest' implies this is enabling an option to set this value not that it is actually setting it, but that's not the case.  

You say: "Even though you have disabled local setting in Tools, the latest files of that specific team project should also be checked out automatically."  -  that's unexpected behaviour and frustratingly crazy !

Comment: Hi@userSteve   We are trying to keep users to get latest version of files when using server workspace. This is how server workspace supposed to use under design of my personal understanding.  You could also take a look at official doc here [When might I need to use a server workspace?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace?view=azure-devops#when-might-i-need-to-use-a-server-workspace) It's specially mentions : **You need to use the Enable get latest on check-out option.**

Comment: I know this is a little confused when users first time to use these settings. But as you already pointed out, it's actually for different usage one for client and one for server project level.  Since you *do not need to use the Enable get latest on check-out option.* I would suggest you switch to local workspace for your scenario.  local workspaces keep multiple copies of the same file to enable some version control actions locally due to the DevOps Server connection not being reliably available. Sorry for any inconvenience.